# React triggering a function within the same file and passing constant data

Tags: reactjs, triggers

I am trying to dynamically update functions in a single file I am exporting to a parent.

```
export function AppButtonClick() {
  
    const [buttonText, setButtonText] = useState('Edit');
    
    function handleClick() {
      buttonText === ('Edit') ?  setButtonText('Save') : setButtonText('Edit');
      
        
      

    }
    
    
 
    return (
     
       <Button onClick={handleClick} variant="contained" color="primary" >
            {buttonText}  </Button>
        
    );
};

export  function FieldChange () { 
  
  const [divinformation, divinfo] = useState(buttonText)  
 
  
  divinformation === ('Save') ? 
  divinfo(<form><input type="text" style={{width: 600, height: 40, fontSize: 16}} /></form>)
  : ""
   
     
 
 return (
     <div >{divinformation}</div>
 
     );
 
 };
```

I am trying to change the input field based on the edit button.

I have attempted to use "useContext" to pass the object details over and did not yield any results.

Comment: what is the relationship between these components?

Comment: AppButtonClick is an edit/save button when clicked to hit edit will change the field for FieldChange to edit (Request Timeout) in this instance into a text field,

Comment: what i'm asking is you are using the buttonText state from AppButtonClick component inside the FieldChange component. so what is the relationship between these components are they siblings?